# Radio button returns wrong value in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a form where a person can enter details about a friend (name, age, gender, address). This friend is displayed in a list view and when a friend from the list is clicked on they have the choice to edit that record.

I can successfully update every detail about a friend except for the gender.

For example:

List view:

```
1) James Bond, 20, Male, Sydney NSW
```

Then I click edit and change it to

```
James smith, 21, Female, Canberra NSW
```

and then back in my list view it will show:

```
1) James smith, 21, Male, Canberra NSW
```

Notice how the gender doesn't change?

I can figure out why this is happening as I use the same logic to change the name and age as i did to change the gender

Here is the relevant code:

`ViewFriend.java` ( this class displays the list view and has the edit option)

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, long id) {
        String text = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        final int ID = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(text.charAt(0)));
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(viewFriends.this);
        builder.setTitle("Notice");
        builder.setMessage("Please select to to edit, delete a friend or cancel");

        // add the buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("Edit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), editOrDelete.class);
                ArrayList<String> result1 = mydb.retrieveRow(ID);
                name = result1.get(1);
                age = result1.get(2);
                gender = result1.get(3);
                address = result1.get(4);
                code = result1.get(0);
                intent.putExtra("code", code);
                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                intent.putExtra("age", age);
                intent.putExtra("gender", gender);
                intent.putExtra("address", address);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        builder.setNeutralButton(" Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                mydb.deleteTitle(ID);
                finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),viewFriends.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
});
```

The code above retrieves the details from the database and passes it to the intent. I have printed the contents of each variable (name, age, gender, address) and they print out correctly.

`editFriend.java` ( this class pre fills the form with the data passed through the intent that displays correctly)

```
  public class editFriend extends AppCompatActivity {
    private  Intent intent;
    private RadioGroup rg;
    private Button update;
    private RadioButton rb;
    private String newName,newAddress,newGender;
    private int newAge;
    EditText ed, ed1;
    public String name,address,gender,age,code;
    private int selectedID,ages,codes;
    NumberPicker numberPicker;
    private databaseManager4 myDataBase;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_editordeletefriend);
        intent= getIntent();
        myDataBase = new databaseManager4(this);
        rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup_update);
        selectedID = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedID);
        ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fullName_update);
        numberPicker = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.resultAge_update);
        numberPicker.setMinValue(6);
        numberPicker.setMaxValue(110);
        numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
        update = (Button)findViewById(R.id.update_button);
        ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.address_update);
        name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        age = intent.getStringExtra("age");
        gender = intent.getStringExtra("gender");
        address = intent.getStringExtra("address");
        code = intent.getStringExtra("code");
        codes = Integer.parseInt(code);
        displayForm();
        newName = ed.getText().toString();
        newAge = numberPicker.getValue();
        newGender = rb.getText().toString();


        update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              
              int id = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);
                if (myDataBase.updateRow(codes,newName,newAge,newGender,ed1.getText().toString())){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"successfully updated the friend "
                           +ed.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
               else{
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could not  update the friend "
                           +ed.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
               intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),viewFriends.class);
               startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void displayForm(){
        ed.setText(name);
        ed1.setText(address);

       if (gender.equals("Male")){
            rb = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.resultGenderMale_update);
        }
         else if (gender.equals("Female"))
        {
            rb = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.resultGenderFemale_update);
        }
        rb.setChecked(true);

        ages= Integer.parseInt(age);
        numberPicker.setValue(ages);


    }
    public void clear(){
        ed.setText("");
        ed1.setText("");
    }
}
```

This is where the issue lies, even if the user clicks on Male it registers as female and i am unsure why.

Any ideas how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you set value of `rb` variable to a single radio button, predefined with previous gender value here

```
if (gender.equals("Male")){
  rb = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.resultGenderMale_update);
}
else if (gender.equals("Female"))
{
  rb = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.resultGenderFemale_update);
}
```

And you read value of the same button then. To fix that in you click listener for update button you need to read checked radio button id using `getCheckedRadioButtonId` on radio group (your `rg` variable).

upd:
this is how your Edit Friend activity code might look like

```
public class EditFriendActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private RadioGroup mGenderRadioGroup;
  private Button mUpdateButton;
  private EditText mNameField;
  private EditText mAddressField;
  private NumberPicker mAgePicker;
  private databaseManager4 mDatabaseManager;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_editordeletefriend);
    initUI();

    mDatabaseManager = new databaseManager4(this);
  }

  private void initUI() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    mNameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fullName_update);
    mNameField.setText(intent.getStringExtra("name"));

    mAddressField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address_update);
    mAddressField.setText(intent.getStringExtra("address"));

    mAgePicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.resultAge_update);
    mAgePicker.setMinValue(6);
    mAgePicker.setMaxValue(110);
    mAgePicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
    mAgePicker.setValue(Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("age")));

    mUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_button);
    mUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(updateClickListener);

    mGenderRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup_update);

    RadioButton targetRadioButton = null;
    switch (Gender.fromString(intent.getStringExtra("gender"))) {
      case MALE:
        targetRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.resultGenderMale_update);
        break;
      case FEMALE:
        targetRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.resultGenderFemale_update);
        break;
    }
    if (targetRadioButton != null) {
      targetRadioButton.setChecked(true);
    }
  }

  public void clear() {
    mNameField.setText("");
    mAddressField.setText("");
  }

  private Gender getSelectedGender() {
    int checkedButtonId = mGenderRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    switch (checkedButtonId) {
      case R.id.resultGenderMale_update:
        return Gender.MALE;
      case R.id.resultGenderFemale_update:
        return Gender.FEMALE;
    }
    return Gender.UNDEFINED;
  }

  private View.OnClickListener updateClickListener =
      new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Gender newGender = getSelectedGender();
          int code = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("code"));
          System.out.println("gender is" + newGender.stringValue);
          if (mDatabaseManager.updateRow(
              code,
              mNameField.getText().toString(),
              mAgePicker.getValue(),
              newGender.stringValue,
              mAddressField.getText().toString())) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "successfully updated the friend " + ed.getText().toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
          } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Could not  update the friend " + ed.getText().toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
          }
          Intent viewFriendsIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), viewFriends.class);
          startActivity(viewFriendsIntent);
          finish();
        }
      };

  private enum Gender {
    UNDEFINED("undefined"),
    MALE("Male"),
    FEMALE("Female");

    private @Nullable String stringValue;

    Gender(@Nullable String stringValue) {
      this.stringValue = stringValue;
    }

    public static Gender fromString(@Nullable String value) {
      if (value != null) {
        for (Gender gender : Gender.values()) {
          if (value.equals(gender.stringValue)) {
            return gender;
          }
        }
      }
      return UNDEFINED;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: not sure i understand...
i added 
int id = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

 rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);

Comment: @william_ it always points to the same radio button.